# DJS Cannot read properties of null (reading 'premium')

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, discord, discord.js

In my code, before it does anything I have it check if there is `data` and if there isnt then make a new mongodb collection but when running the command and there is no collection it returns the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'premium')` and then it creates the mongodb collection so when i run it the second time it works, how would i make the collection create first then run the command?

Code:

```
    run: async (interaction, client) => {

        const data = await guildSchema.findOne({
            id: interaction.guild.id
        });

        if (!data) {
            const newData = new guildSchema({
                id: interaction.guild.id,
                name: interaction.guild.name
            })
            newData.save();
        }

        const types = interaction.options.getString('type');
        const modules = interaction.options.getString('module');
        
        if (types === 'type_enable') {
            if (modules === 'module_all') {

                if (!data.premium) {    
                    await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                        logChannel: interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id,
                        welcomeChannel: interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id,
                        goodbyeChannel: interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id,
                    })
    
                    await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
                        new: true
                    })

                    interaction.reply('test')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning the variable and then creating the doc if it doesn't find a document, you will need to fetch from the database again after creating the new document.

```
if (!data) {
    const newData = new guildSchema({
        id: interaction.guild.id,
        name: interaction.guild.name
    })
    newData.save();

    data = await guildSchema.findOne({
        id: interaction.guild.id
    });
}
```

Comment: this does not fix it and was less than helpful i do not need to add that and it gives the exact same issue as before as its still doesn't see the document in time before sending the slash command